# Capybara test user sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

i'm run into the problem with testing user sign in procces

here my test

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
include Devise::TestHelpers

describe "UserSignin" do
  it "should allow a registered user to sign in" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:employer, :email => "email@email.com")
    user.confirm! 
    visit "/users/sign_in"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    fill_in "Password", :with => "12345678"
    click_button "Sign in"
    current_path.should == '/employer'
    expect(page).to have_content('My Account')
  end
end
```

if it's improtant i'm using device for authentication

in factory i also have `:employer` factory

problem with authenticate

after clicking `sign_in` i'v  got an error `invalid email or  password`

**UPDATE**

there was problem with configs for test environment in spec helper

the solution is to set:

`DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation`

Comment: Please, show your spec_helper.rb

Comment: Do you have any uniqueness constraints on the email address in the employer model?  Does the password definitely match?  Does it work in the browser?

Comment: Can you also please provide your factory file, so we see how password is set ?

Comment: i figured out this problem changing configs to test environment

Comment: `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` in spec helper